# Nested namespaces: how to retrieve inner nodes

Tags: php, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have this scenario, returned by a SOAP WS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:myFunctionEnvelopeName xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:ns1="http://fooNameSpace.comm">
            <myFunctionName xmlns="http://barNameSpace.com">
                [some nodes here]
            </myFunctionName>
        </ns1:myFunctionEnvelopeName>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to select subnodes child of `myFunctionName` but I have some issues

- If i register `ns1` namespace into my `XPath` I'm able only to select `myFunctionEnevelopeName` (even if I try with `getElementsByTagName()` I receive back 0 nodes
- If I register, let's say, `ns2` with `barNameSpace.com`, my query will not return my elements

  - If I don't register any namespace my query will not return my elements

Only workaround I have found is to

- Register `ns1` as namespace of `XPath`
- Retrieve "main node" (`myFunctionEnevelopeName`)
- Extract `textContent` from "main node" (that of course is a valid xml)
- Create a brand-new `Xpath` with the text content obtained
- Register `ns2` as namespace of brand-new `Xpath`
- Obtain what I want

I'm sure that exists a clever method to do that, but maybe I don't know it. Someone could give me pointers?

Answer (score 0):

XPath itself doesn't prevent you from registering multiple namespaces and you can therefore use several prefixes in an XPath expression. For example `/ns1:element-1/ns2:element-2`. Using no prefix at all is the same as matching elements that don't have a namespace.

DOM API has the method `getElementsByTagNameNS()` for matching elements with a namespace.

Comment: If I do a query like `//ns1:myFunctionEnvelopeName/myFunctionName/myNode` I dind't get anything back, so I suppose that only way for me is to follow my method ...

Comment: In that query `myFunctionName` doesn't belong to any namespace, but in your example document `myFunctionName` has a namespace defintion, declared as a default namespace.

Comment: So how can I query for default ns? Have I to query with `xmlns` prefix?

Comment: Just the same way you query a prefixed namespace. You register a namespace-URI to prefix -mapping and use that prefix in your XPath query. XPath doesn't require the prefix to be the same that is used in the document. How the namespace registration is done, depends on the language/library/XPath framework/engine that you use.

Comment: I'll try and let you know ;)

Comment: @DonCallisto If you are using DOMXPath, use `registerNamespace`  http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php

Comment: yes, I know how to register a namespace. Maybe you're not understand my question ;-)

Comment: In that case you should please clarify what your question is.